# SQL Export Data from a Query to Use Tilde (~)

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv, tilde

I have a basic Select query which brings me back a set of results (roughly around 100,000 records) which I currently have to export to .CSV Format , issue is I then have to remove the commas out of the results and replace it with a (~). Which I do using a file format application that I got off the web.

But I'm trying to go about making this automated (if possible) to save time. Like e.g run off a stored procedure that can do this for me export the file in a (~) format.

Does anyone have any tips how this stored procedure can be written or an pointers would be appreciated.

p.s I have tried to use the export wizard but it just just crashes due to too many records.

```
Expected Result

 Test1~Test2~Test3
   5~6~7
```

(sql Script which I am running)

```
 select 
'SPK' as [AGENCY_CODE], -- should be set to SPK
'OBCALL' as [MEDIA_CODE], -- should be set to OBCALL
isnull(c.salutation,'') as [TITLE],
isnull(c.otherName,'') as [FORENAME],
isnull(c.name,'') as [SURNAME],
isnull(c.attTXT64,'') as [STANDARDISED_NAME],
replace(isnull(c.addr1, ''), ',', '.') AS [BEST_ADDRESS_LINE_1],
replace(isnull(c.addr2, ''), ',', '.') AS [BEST_ADDRESS_LINE_2],
replace(isnull(c.addr3, ''), ',', '.') AS [BEST_ADDRESS_LINE_3],
replace(isnull(c.addr4, ''), ',', '.') AS [BEST_ADDRESS_LINE_4],
isnull(c.postCode,'') as [BEST_POSTCODE],
--'0' + isnull(c.phone1,'') as [TELEPHONE_N2O],-- should be populated with the spare field ORIG_TEL .
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), c.phone1), 11) as [TELEPHONE_NO],-- should be populated with the spare field ORIG_TEL .
convert(varchar(100),c.attDT03,120) as [DATE_TIMESTAMP],
isnull(c.attTXT10,'') as [SM_CONTACT_KEY],
isnull(c.attTXT89,'') as [ SM_ADDRESS_KEY], 
isnull(c.attTXT11,'') as [ CAMPAIGN_IDENTIFIER],
isnull(c.attTXT12,'') as [ WAVE_ID],
isnull(c.attTXT13,'') as [OLDSTACK_NEWSTACK_FLAG],
isnull(c.attTXT14,'') as [MARKET_3_FLAG],
isnull(c.attTXT15,'') as [ADSL_2_FLAG],
isnull(c.attTXT16,'') as [FIBRE_FLAG],
isnull(c.attTXT17,'') as [LOAD_ID],
isnull(c.attTXT18,'') as [CONTACT_POINT_KEY],
isnull(c.attTXT19,'') as [DATA_POOL_URN],
isnull(c.attTXT20,'') as [EVENT_KEY],
isnull(c.attTXT21,'') as [BILLING_ACCOUNT_KEY] ,
isnull(c.attTXT22,'') as [CAMPAIGN_SOURCE] ,
isnull(c.attTXT23,'') as [CAMPAIGN_CODE] ,
isnull(c.attTXT24,'') as [ CMT_ROLE_KEY],
isnull(c.attTXT25,'') as [ CMT_LOCATION_KEY],
isnull(c.attTXT26,'') as [BILL_ACCNT_NUM], 
isnull(c.attTXT27,'') as  [BILLING_ACCOUNT_TYPE],
--All other fields are as per the import record values
--DATE/TIME_OF_CONTRACT to CONTRACT_END_DATE_SUPPLIER3

CASE WHEN dx.datetime IS NULL THEN convert(varchar,getdate(),120) ELSE CONVERT(varchar, dx.datetime, 120) END
as [DATE/TIMEOF CONTACT],

Case when uc.campaignid = 3 then 'CT001' when uc.campaignid = 22 then 'CT001'  when uc.campaignid = 18 then 'CT011'  
     when uc.campaignid = 26 then 'CT013'
end as [CAMPAIGN_TYPE], -- map to BT/DATA/10.CAMPAIGN_Code (return CAMPAIGN_TYPE)
ISNULL((    CASE 
            WHEN dx.[Abandon] = 1 THEN 'OC039'
            ELSE d.code END),'OC042') 
 AS [OUTCOME_CODE], -- populate with (OC001-OCxxx)

'TM' as [CHANNEL_MEDIA_CODE], --= (TBC)
isnull(c.email,'') as [EMAIL_ADDRESS], -- populate with EMAIL_ADDRESS
'' as [EMAIL_CONSENT], --= populate with EMAIL_CONSENT ***************
'' as [INBOUND_TELEPHONE_NUMBER], --*****************
'' as [COMPETITOR_SUPPLIER_1], -- CONT CONTRACT_END_DATE_SUPPLIER3 – poplulate ***********
'' as [PRODUCT_FROM_SUPPLIER1], -- populate ************
'' as [CONTRACT_START_DATE_SUPPLIER1], --*****
'' as [CONTRACT_END_DATE_SUPPLIER1], --*****
'' as [COMPETITOR_SUPPLIER2], --****
'' as [PRODUCT_FROM_SUPPLIER2], --****
'' as [CONTRACT_START_DATE_SUPPLIER2],-- *****
'' as [CONTRACT_END_DATE_SUPPLIER2], --*****
'' as [COMPETITOR_SUPPLIER3],-- ****
'' as [PRODUCT_FROM_SUPPLIER3],--****
'' as [CONTRACT_START_DATE_SUPPLIER3],-- *****
'' as [CONTRACT_END_DATE_SUPPLIER3],-- *****

--ORDER_NUM to NUMBER_OF_CALLS_MADE
isnull(c.attTXT02,'') as [ORDER_NUM], -- Captured by Operator
isnull(dx.duration,0) as [CALL_DURATION],
-------------dxi.talk as [CALL_DURATION], -- populate difference start/end time (seconds)******
isnull(c.attTXT09,'') as [WARMTH_RATING_NOW], -- captured by agent
isnull(c.attTXT80,'') as [WARMTH_RATING_FUTURE_CAMPAIGNS], -- captured by agent
isnull(dx.callid,'') [SOURCE_INTERACTION_ID],
-------------isnull(a.id,'') as [SOURCE_INTERACTION_ID], -- Tpoints unique call Identifier --- Activity ID *******
isnull(uc.callcount,'') as [NUMBER_OF_CALLS_MADE],

(select left(ethnicOrigin, 1))  as [CALL_CONSENT_VALIDATE_FLG], -- ******** gift aid status - first byte only
(select left(nationality, 5)) as [CALL_CONSENT_OUTCOME_CD], -- ******** nationality - first 5 bytes only

--QUESTION _1 to ANSWER_3
isnull(c.attTXT56,'') as [QUESTION_1], -- populate from SPARE_FIELD_28
isnull(c.attTXT51,'') as [ANSWER_1], -- captured by the agent if SPARE_FIELD_1  populated
isnull(c.attTXT29,'') as [QUESTION_2], -- poaddingpulate from SPARE_FIELD_28
isnull(c.attTXT67,'') as [ANSWER_2], -- captured by the agent if SPARE_FIELD_2  populated
isnull(c.attTXT37,'') as [QUESTION_3], -- populate from SPARE_FIELD_28
isnull(c.attTXT58,'') as [ANSWER_3] -- captured by the agent if SPARE_FIELD_3  populated
--isnull(c.attdt18,GETDATE()) as [Export_Date]

from 
    u_contact c with (nolock)
inner join u_campaigncontact uc with (nolock) on uc.contactid = c.id 
inner join u_dispcode d with (nolock) on d.id = uc.resultcodeid
outer apply (select top 1 duration, callid, 
case when outcome = 113 then 1 else 0 end [Abandon], [datetime] from dxi_cdrlog cdr where cdr.urn = c.id order by callid desc) dx
 where 
     uc.campaignid in (3, 18, 22, 26) and d.dmc = 1 and c.created between DATEADD(week, -1, getdate()) AND  getdate()
and c.importid > 0
```

Comment: Which database are you using? MySql / MS-SQL / PostGres ? There are different approaches for different systems.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard identifiers. But you should also add which _tool_ you use to run the export? @cars10: It's Postgres (or PostgreSQL). There is no uppercase G in the name.

Comment: There are several tools (SSIS, bcp, sqlcmd) that can export data and none of them requires decimal replacement in the SQL statement itself. You simply have to specify the proper separators, culture and/or decimal separators when exporting

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL-Server you could use the command line tool `sqlcmd` which comes with the package. You might have to re-run the installation of the SSMS to acticvate the option.

Open `cmd.exe`. When you use the `sqlcmd` command with the options

```
sqlcmd -S host -d dbname -U username -P password -W -s ~ -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT 1,'hello world'"
```

It should get you

```
1~hello world
```

`-W` removes blanks between the columns, `-s ~` sets `~` as the column separator, `-h -1` removes the header line at the top and `-Q` then expects the actual query statement as the next argument.

Obviously for the actual job you need to call your SELECt statement. It might be a good idea to define a view (`myview`) for the job and in the `sqlcmd` just do a `SELECT * FROM myview` since writing a multiline SQL command within a cmd environment is *not so much fun ...*. Of course it is *possible* but it is not really worth the hassle.

The command should then redirect its output directly into a file like

```
set sql=SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM myview
set scmd=sqlcmd -S host -d dbname -U username -P password -W -s ~ -h -1 -Q

%scmd% "%sql" > exportfile.csv
```

Comment: You *don't* have to reinstall SSMS to use `sqlcmd`, it's part of the server itself. It works even if you don't have SSMS installed.

Comment: Well, in may case I don't have the sql-server installed on my machine and *only* use SSMS to access the database on our central server. That is why I need the SSMS installation.

Comment: @cars10 this threw a error , error connecting to sql server

Comment: You probably also need to specify the name of the database you want to connect to `-d dbname`, see my updated post.